# Swiper v9 - Lazy loading with background image

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to make the lazyload working with background images with the latest version of Swiper (v9), imported via CDN.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything on the documentation that really helps...

What I tried so far is this HTML for the single slide:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
     <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622015663319-e97e697503ee?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
</div>
```

And setting these config:

```
preloadImages: true,
lazy: true,
lazyPreloadPrevNext: 1,
```

But nothing happens.
Here's the full code I'm using:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new Swiper(".swiper", {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            type: 'fraction'
        },
        preloadImages: true,
        lazy: true,
        lazyPreloadPrevNext: 1
    });
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622015663319-e97e697503ee?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605114967-8130f3a36994?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600573472556-e636c2acda88?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582268611958-ebfd161ef9cf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608058204446-1cf0f7d11d38?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570630573374-478e1be58533?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895942-01dcb0737923?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661902468735-eabf780f8ff6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895754-2772f8a08f6b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination count"></div>
</div>
```

[Here's also a pen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/rNQBaVM) if it's easier to debug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading):

> Since version 9 Swiper doesn't have a specific lazy loading API, as it relies on native browser lazy loading feature.

However, there is no lazy loading feature for CSS `background-image`, so you'd have to implement your own. Here is a primitive example to get you started:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new Swiper(".swiper", {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            type: 'fraction'
        },
        modules: [
          ({ swiper, on }) => {
            on('init activeIndexChange', () => {
              const lazy = swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex || 0].querySelector('.swiper-lazy');
              if (!lazy.style.backgroundImage) {
                lazy.style.backgroundImage = `url(${lazy.dataset.background})`;
              }
            });
          },
        ],
    });
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  height: 90vh;
}

.swiper-lazy {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622015663319-e97e697503ee?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605114967-8130f3a36994?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600573472556-e636c2acda88?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582268611958-ebfd161ef9cf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608058204446-1cf0f7d11d38?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570630573374-478e1be58533?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895942-01dcb0737923?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661902468735-eabf780f8ff6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-lazy" data-background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895754-2772f8a08f6b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination count"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could use `<img>` tags for lazy loading, with some CSS to make them behave like `background-image`:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new Swiper(".swiper", {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            type: 'fraction'
        },
    });
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  height: 90vh;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622015663319-e97e697503ee?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605114967-8130f3a36994?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600573472556-e636c2acda88?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582268611958-ebfd161ef9cf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608058204446-1cf0f7d11d38?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570630573374-478e1be58533?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895942-01dcb0737923?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661902468735-eabf780f8ff6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602774895754-2772f8a08f6b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" loading="lazy"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination count"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiperJs version 9 and above doesn't support lazyLoad for `background-image`, if you need `background-image` behave, you could use `<img>` tag with this styles:

```
.swiper-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  -o-object-position: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper">
       <div class="swiper-wrapper">
           <div class="swiper-slide">
               <img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" />
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide">
               <img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format.jpg&w=2000&q=90" />
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```